# Is ARC clockwise or counter clockwise?

Tags: geometry

I have an ARC. For ARC I have an below information :

1. Start point.
2. End point.
3. Another third point on ARC.
4. Center point.

Below image shows in Detail :

[image]

Now the question is how to check ARC is clock wise or counter clockwise?

Comment: Means the points which are used to draw an arc. How to check it?

Answer (score 4):

In **2D** you can exploit cross product which returns perpendicular vector to vectors multiplied. The side on which it points is dependend on the order of multiplicants (CW/CCW) so if you got vectors `v1,v2` then `v1 x v2 = - (v2 x v1)`. if `v1,v2` are 2D vectors then the result of their cross lies only in **Z-coordinate** so:

Let's starting point is **SP**, ending point is **EP**, and some middle point is **MP**.
Form vectors **SE = EP - SP** and **SM = MP - SP** and calculate the sign of **Z-coordinate** of their cross product.

```
CP = SE.X * SM.Y - SE.Y * SM.X
```

Arc is clockwise if cross product is positive and anti-clockwise if negative (or the other way around it depends on how is your **2D coordinate system** defined).

Work example for arcs Red-Green-Blue, right one is small arc, left two are large arcs:

[image]

function used (note that sign < 0 is for my left-handed coordinate system)

```
function IsCW(sx, sy, mx, my, ex, ey: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   Result := (ex-sx) * (my-sy) - (ey-sy) * (mx-sx) < 0;
end;
```

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for addition. I don't understand - how I could to approve your corrections? (BTW, I think that phrase about Z-coordinate isn't necessary)

Comment: I think it is necessary because dimensionality is not specified and in 3D you need to apply `dot(reference_plane_normal,cross(SE,SM))` instead. Also for those this QA is helpful usually does not have this knowledge and if missed could lead to wrong results and lot of confusion ...

Comment: @Spektre  OK. There is no clear `clockwise` conception in 3D, but this discussion would be useful for author.