# How to determine if arc is clockwise or not?

Tags: c#, math, geometry

lately I have been struggling with arcs and their direction.
I have arc built on three points. Lets call them **FirstPoint, MiddlePoint** and **LastPoint**.
I need to determine if they are going clockwise or counterclockwise.
I tried the solution from here [Is ARC clockwise or counter clockwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960924/is-arc-clockwise-or-counter-clockwise). However, it gives me wrong results. Im stuck with something like that:

```
public bool IsClockwise()
        {
            Vector se = new Vector(LastPoint.X - FirstPoint.X, LastPoint.Y - LastPoint.Y);
            Vector sm = new Vector(MiddlePoint.X - FirstPoint.X, MiddlePoint.Y - FirstPoint.Y);
            double cp = Vector.CrossProduct(se, sm);
            if (cp > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The standard for rotation is counter clockwise direction is positive.  Zero degrees is the positive x-axis and 90 degrees is the positive y axis.  It is called the right hand rule of thumb where the thumb points in the positive z axis.

Comment: "clockwise" depends on your coordinate system. Do you get inverse results always? If so, just reverse if-condition.

Comment: Your code is full of bugs. In `se`, you're assigning `0` to `.Y`.

Comment: what if its in a straight line?

Comment: Look here: `LastPoint.Y - LastPoint.Y`

Comment: @DanielA.White then the cross product (really, the outer product in 2D) will be 0. Whether tha'ts CW or CCW is up to the application.

Comment: @DanielA.White it can`t be in straight line, @MBo sorry guys, too much hours looking at the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. In your sample, you calculate `se` as

```
Vector se = new Vector(LastPoint.X - FirstPoint.X, LastPoint.Y - LastPoint.Y);
```

Note that the second term is always zero.

Also, your two vectors should be from the midpoint to the first point, and from the midpoint to the last point. I suppose you *could* use vectors from the first point to the mid point and last point, but that's really not how it's typically done. It just feels wrong.

```
    public bool IsClockwise()
    {
        Vector se = new Vector(LastPoint.X - MiddlePoint.X, LastPoint.Y - MiddlePoint.Y);
        Vector sm = new Vector(FirstPoint.X - MiddlePoint.X, FirstPoint.Y - MiddlePoint.Y);
        double cp = Vector.CrossProduct(se, sm);

        return cp > 0;
    }
```

Comment: My mistake. I tried this. However it still gives wrong results.

Comment: @maciejpuzianowski Define "wrong results." Is it the opposite of what you expect? Is it consistent? Is it always wrong? Getting zero or NaN?

Comment: `cp` should be `> 0' then its working. Thank you very much, Im new to vectors.

Comment: @maciejpuzianowski Glad to help. Note that your `Vector` type might have arithmetic overloads depending on what library they're from. If that's the case, you could just do `var se = LastPoint - MiddlePoint;` Doesn't really matter but it can help clean up the code some.