# Determine if arc is clockwise or not for big arcs (>260 deg)

Tags: math, geometry, formula, calculation, degrees

So I have an arc described as a start point, end point and it's centre point. So I can easily determine angles, radious, middle point.

I've used the formula from this question
[How to determine if arc is clockwise or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565878/how-to-determine-if-arc-is-clockwise-or-not?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And it works fine for small and medium arcs, but gives the wrong result for big arcs (around 300 degrees), What is the proper way to determine is big arc is clockwise or not?

Comment: Have you checked solution from [link from your link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33963353/844416)? (just added a picture)

Comment: @MBo yes, it's not working for big arcs for me.. Probably I need to doublecheck how I find the middle point, maybe error is there

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The line by the two endpoints decomposes the whole circle in a great and a small arc. By plugging the coordinates of the intermediate point as well as of the circle center in the line equation, you know which is the relevant arc, by comparing the signs. You can draw the orientation from this knowledge.

[image]

Comment: Hm, I've seen formulas that use EP, ST and centre _or_ EP, ST and middle point. Have never been one that use all four.. How can I use them all?

Comment: @Bruice: if I am right, the signed area of the triangle formed by the center and the endpoints tells you  the orientation of the great arc.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have Delphi question, so you perhaps can reproduce that manual test. Left mouse button click for arc start (Red), middle for middle (Green), right for arc end (Blue).

`IsCW` works for left-handed coordinates system, for right-handed one change comparison to `>`

```
uses... Math;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  R: Integer = 200;
  cx: Integer = 300;
  cy: Integer = 300;
  sx, sy, mx, my, ex, ey: Integer;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  l: Double;
begin
  l := Hypot(x - cx, y - cy) + 0.1;
  case Button of
    mbLeft: begin
      sx := cx + Round((x-cx)*R / l);
      sy := cy + Round((y-cy)*R / l);
    end;
    mbMiddle: begin
      mx := cx + Round((x-cx)*R / l);
      my := cy + Round((y-cy)*R / l);
    end;
    mbRight:
    begin
      ex := cx + Round((x-cx)*R / l);
      ey := cy + Round((y-cy)*R / l);
    end;
  end;
  Refresh;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);

function IsCW(sx, sy, mx, my, ex, ey: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   Result := (ex-sx) * (my-sy) - (ey-sy) * (mx-sx) < 0;
end;

var
  a, bx, by, c: Double;
  s:string;

begin
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Pen.Width := 3;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Ellipse(cx -  r, cy - r, cx + r + 1, cy + r + 1);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.Ellipse(sx - 3, sy - 3, sx + 4, sy + 4);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clLime;
  Canvas.Ellipse(mx - 3, my - 3, mx + 4, my + 4);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlue;
  Canvas.Ellipse(ex - 3, ey - 3, ex + 4, ey + 4);
  if IsCW(sx, sy, mx, my, ex, ey) then
    s := 'CW'
  else
    s := 'CCW';
  Canvas.TextOut(cx - 20, cy - 20, s);
end;
```